# Do I need different objects of PreparedStatement for each different SQL Query?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am working on a java application and using Derby Database.

I have one object of PreparedStatement named pstmt.

1) Can I use same object (here pstmt) for every SELECT Statements like these and others Statements (Would it be an efficient way) ?

For Ex:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE .....");
```

or I have to create different objects per different SQL Statement like below..

```
pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE .....");
```

2) And what about other Statements like CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE etc. Can I use a common object for each type of operation (like one object for every SELECT Statements, one for every INSERT, one for UPDATE Statements and so on..)

I know the advantages of it but I am confused with efficient usage of it.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `conn.prepareStatement` you are creating a new **object** (assuming the `Connection` object isn't some sort of caching factory pattern, which is probably a safe assumption to make). But from your question you aren't asking about using the same **object**, but reusing the same **variable**, `pstmt`. There's nothing wrong with doing that, just make sure to `close()` the previous one, otherwise you'd be leaking cursors:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
// Missing pstmt.close();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY NAME");
```

The second assingment loses the reference to the previous `pstmt`, without `close()` being called on it. Hopefully, it will be closed when the garbage collector picks it up (depending on the database-specific implementation of the JDBC driver). But even if it does, you're leaving a dangling cursor open until the garbage collector finally gets round to it.

Comment: What is caching factory pattern and leaking cursors ? Can you attach any link to refer these ?

Comment: A leaking cursor is any statement you didn't `close()`. Wrt caching - a `Connection` object can, in theory, return a previously used `PreparedStatement` object if it already prepared the same string (i.e., a cache), although I admit I've yet to encounter a JDBC implementation that did so.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to reuse same `PreparedStatement`. I would rather say that it is more efficient way than creating multiple `PreparedStatement` objects. For further details, you can go through this link http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/reusing-statements/#N129B1

About the second doubt, instead of using different `PrepareStatement` objects for `CREATE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, (if the use doesn't overlap) you can even reuse single `PreparedStatement` object for all the statements.

Comment: "if the use doesn't overlap" - What does this means ?

Comment: So I can work with a **single** object for any type of statements ?

Comment: @santosh-patil, My understanding in the link provided is slightly different. The article (provided in the link) talks about reusing same `PreparedStatement` with same SQL but different parameters or no parameters. Question, as per what I understand, asks about using the same variable for different PreparedStatement SQLs, which in turn would introduce different DB objects. Better if you could add some other reference to justify your answer.